Latest updates from this morning, broke my webcam
When I logged in this morning, there were a number of updates ready to install.
I installed the updates.
About an hour later, I attempted to conduct a video call using Viber.
Viber could not see my built-in web camera.
These latest updates broke my webcam.
How do I fix my webcam issue?

In trying to troubleshoot the issue, the webcam DOES seem to be working in Telegram.  For some reason, it's only Viber that can not access the webcam.

"this morning, there were a number of updates ready to install" is too vague to be useful. Find your apt log in /var/log/apt and show us the actual list of packages updated just today.

Is viber installed as a snap app? If so, switching to the APT version may work
